# DYLD, Library not loaded - Only happens in Test Flight

Tags: ios, cocoapods, testflight, dyld

Trying to build a cordova project with cocoapods in xcode 10 and everything works fine in debug mode but when published to Testflight it just insta-crashes with the error message.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Description: DYLD, Library not loaded: @rpath/mediastreamer2.framework/mediastreamer2 | Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/5EB1FE06-D8EC-479A-BC36-C7CD1F55C9A2/Intulse.app/Intulse | Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find: | /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5EB1FE06-D8EC-479A-BC36-C7CD1F55C9A2/Intulse.app/Frameworks/mediastreamer2.framework/mediastreamer2: mremap_encrypted() => -1, errno=12 for /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5EB1FE06-D8EC-479A-BC36-C7CD1F55C9A2/Intulse.app/Frameworks/mediastreamer2.framework/mediastreamer2
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

- I have tried setting Bitcode to no in both my projects.

[image]

- I have also set the it to optional in the linked library.

[image]

- Cleaned & rebuilt
- Runpath Search Paths is set to @executable_path/Frameworks
- Signing is set to "Automatically Manage Signing" and under build settings it is set to "iOS Developer"
- Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries set to "Yes"
- Recreated the provisioning profile
- Side loaded the Release build of the app using the Apple Configurator 2 (doesn't crash).
- Changed the schema under archive to debug
- Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority set to "Use System Defaults"

[image]

I expected it to run in test flight but just instantly crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you import linphone like this:

```
pod 'liblinphone'
```

You can solve this problem by importing:

```
source "https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/podspec.git"
pod 'linphone-sdk' , '4.2'
```

reference：
https://wiki.linphone.org/xwiki/wiki/public/view/Lib/Getting%20started/iOS/